# For which groups is (non-)left orderability decidable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, 3-manifolds, ordered-groups

Mainly, my question is in the title, but let me be more precise here.

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group with solvable word problem. If G is not left-orderable, is there an finite-time algorithm to establish this fact?

If the answer to the above question is unknown, is it known in the case $G$ is the fundamental group of a 3-manifold? Or is there a class of groups where it is known?

Comment: Given your assumptions, then there is an algorithm. Solvable word problem means that one may construct the Cayley graph to some radius. If there is a total order on the ball of radius R compatible with all multiplications that land in that ball, for all R, then the group is orderable. So by the contrapositive, if it is not orderable, then there is some R such that any ordering on a ball of radius R in the Cayley graph is inconsistent. 

The difficult thing is to show that groups (including 3-manifold groups) are orderable. Without the caveat that $G$ is non-orderable, then this is open.

Comment: @IanAgol,  I don't understand the comment. First of all how do you know that if each ball is orderable then you can find a consistent order for all balls? And granting that, you still seem to be arguing orderability is co-re unless you can bound how big the bad R is.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Going from an ordering on balls to an ordering of the group is a compactness argument: If the R -ball is orderable for all R, then we can find an ordering on the R-ball for all R which restricts to the chosen ordering on the R-1-ball, since there are only finitely many orderings on each R ball for every R. 

This is not co-recursive, as you say, since we don't have a bound on how big the bad R is. But the hypothesis that the group is not orderable guarantees that some bad R exists, hence is recursive modulo an oracle that tells you the group is not orderable.

Comment: @IanAgol, I agree with the compactness argument.

Comment: The question is unclear. What's the input? Starting with "let $G$ be a group" sounds like $G$ is fixed. There should be something like some presentiation is the input...! The title even sounds like it's senseless. For a given group, the veracity of left-orderability is a Boolean variable.

Comment: For the question to make sense presumably the solution to the word problem is the input.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I'm not sure what you mean. Solution of word problem for what? Where is the group? And what's the output then?

Comment: I would have expected that the input is a group presentation of a group $G$, the output is Yes/No, in such a way if the word problem is solvable in $G$, then the program stops and outputs Yes/No according to whether $G$ is left-orderable.

Comment: @YCor, a group can be given by a Turing machine solving it's word problem. The generators are the input alphabet of the Turing machine and you get a recursive presentation by saying all accepted words are 1. If you want to use the decidability of the word problem the Turing machine for the word problem should be part of the input.

Comment: @YCor, if you prefer to work with presentations, you can restrict to some class of groups with uniformly solvable word problem.

Comment: @HJRW I don't prefer anything, I'm trying to obtain from the OP a clarification, which is not made so far.

Comment: Something more or less lurking behind Ian's argument is the following classical fact: a group is non-left-orderable iff there exists $k,\ell\ge 1$ and elements $x_1,\dots,x_k\neq 1$ and all $x_1\in\{x_1,x_1^{-1}\}\dots$, $x_k\in\{x_k,x_k^{-1}\}$ there exist $i_1,\dots,i_\ell\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ such that $y_{i_1}y_{i_2}\dots y_{i_\ell}=1$. So indeed if the solution to WP is part of the input then one can compute until we find such "$(k,\ell)$-torsion" and detect non-left-orderability.

Comment: @YCor, the question is phrased in a way that is pretty standard (if slightly non-rigorous) when talking about these questions.  Benjaming Steinberg already gave the way in which it is usually interpreted.  In most practical situations, one is actually working in a class of finitely presented groups in which the word problem is uniformly decidable, at which point one can interpret it as asking for a decision procedure for presentations.

Comment: I can imagine that there could be a class of groups for which you prove that they had solvable word problem, but for which you did not know an algorithm (or perhaps even you could prove that there was no such algorithm) to construct the algorithm that solved the word problem.

Comment: @DerekHolt -- sure: the class of groups with solvable word problem is such a class!

Comment: @HJRW I'm somewhat not convinced that I should be satisfied by phrasing of questions which (1) give a strong suspicion that the person who asked the question does not know exactly what (s)he's asking, namely is not aware that an algorithmic question involves an input, and that "a group" is not an acceptable input (2) given my best efforts, stay several potential interpretations which don't make the question senseless of trivial, and for which other users like Benjamin provide an interpretation distinct from any I could guess.

Comment: @YCor, if you look up the asker, you'll see that he knows a lot about algorithms.  Also, if you read the question carefully, you'll see that the given input is not a "group", but a "*finitely presented* group".  As you know, a "finitely presented group" (as distinct from a *finitely presentable* group) is a group equipped with a finite presentation, which is clearly a perfectly acceptable input for an algorithm.  I'm puzzled that you find it difficult to figure out what the question is asking for. It was quite clear to me.

Comment: @HJRW Before Benjamin's comment I expected that the input was just a finite presentation and in case the word problem is solvable, the output is "NO" if the group is non-left-orderable.

Comment: @YCor -- well that's correct. But of course the abstract knowledge that the word problem is solvable isn't enough; one needs to have access to the solution to the word problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very nice question, which I don't know how to answer. But I hope the following (shameless self-promotion) will be of interest.

You seem to be looking for some sort of local condition that certifies the (non-)existence of an ordering. Lars Louder and I [made the following definition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2540), which seems to encapsulate a certain simple class of orders in a finite amount of data.

[image: An example of a good stacking]

> **Definition:** Consider a finite, 2-dimensional cell complex $X$ given by the following data: a finite disjoint union of circles $\mathbb{S}$ and an immersion to a finite graph
>   $$
> \partial:\mathbb{S}\to\Gamma ~.
> $$
>   [Hopefully it's clear that $\Gamma$ is the 1-skeleton of $X$ and $\partial$ is the coproduct of the attaching maps of the 2-cells.]
>   A *stacking* of $\partial$ is an *embedding* $\hat{\partial}:\mathbb{S}\to\Gamma\times\mathbb{R}$ so that $\pi\circ\hat{\partial}=\partial$ (ie $\hat{\partial}$ is a lift of $\partial$).
>
> A point $x$ of $\mathbb{S}$ is called *upper* if, whenever $\partial(x)=\partial(y)$, the $\mathbb{R}$-coordinate of $\hat{\partial}(x)$ is greater than the $\mathbb{R}$-coordinate of $\hat{\partial}(y)$.  Lower points are defined similarly.
>
> The stacking $\hat{\partial}$ is called *good* if every component of $\mathbb{S}$ contains at least one upper point *and* at least one lower point.

It's easy to see that the existence of a stacking is equivalent to an order on a certain finite subset of the group; so in particular, if $\pi_1X$ is orderable then a stacking exists.  More interestingly, goodness enables a kind of converse.

> **Proposition:** If $X$ admits a good stacking then $\pi_1X$ is left-orderable.

More precisely, you can deduce from our results that, if $X$ has a good stacking, then $\pi_1X$ is locally indicable, and it then follows that $\pi_1X$ is orderable by the Burns--Hale theorem.  (It would be nice to have a more direct proof of this fact!)

Note that a good stacking can be found algorithmically.  In particular, this provides the kind of "local certificiation" of orderability that I think is relevant to the question.

The following can also be deduced from our results.

> **Proposition:** A finitely presented subgroup $H$ of a one-relator group has a presentation complex with a good stacking if and only if $H$ is torsion-free.

So this provides a class of examples (with solvable word problem) in which orderability can be algorithmically determined.

I would tentatively conjecture that there are other classes of examples that good stackings can also certify in this way.  For instance, it's possible that the fundamental group of any compact, irreducible 3-manifold with boundary admits a presentation complex with a good stacking.

Unfortunately, there's no chance of applying this to closed 3-manifolds, since 2-complexes with good stackings are automatically aspherical. But perhaps there's some modification that works?

Comment: I'd be delighted to know what you're answering. I only have a rough guess based on your comments and Benjamin's. My most plausible guess is the following: the question is whether there is an algorithm where the input is a group presentation and a possible algorithm for the word problem; the algorithm runs and when the algorithm of the input indeed solves the word problem for this presentation in the input, it stops in finite time with answer YES/NO giving a correct answer to the question "does the given group presentation define a left-orderable group?".

Comment: @YCor, well, the question actually only asks for a one-sided algorithm that answers "NO" if the given fp group is not left-orderable. But my answer describes a YES/NO algorithm, as in your comment, that works in the class of finitely presented subgroups of one-relator groups.